# Calander in 2.2 unable to query instances > Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/instances/when

Tags: android, android-calendar

Can anyone plese help me with the following code, the problem is with

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
```

which throws an Unkown URL  illegal argument exception see below

Thanks

Graham

code
    Fetch a list of all calanders, iterate through all calanders using the calander ids

```
package gb.org;




import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Example {

            public static void readCalendar(Context context) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the
        // user has them selected for display.

        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                 (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null); 


        HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();




        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
            final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
            final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

            System.out.println("Calendar is " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);

            //DETERMINE IF CALENDAR IS SELECTED IF YES THEN USE IT 

            calendarIds.add(_id);
        }

        // query the instance table         
        for (String id : calendarIds) {

            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon(); 


            Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                    new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + id,
                    null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 

            while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {

                long  timeNow=System.currentTimeMillis();  //the current time 

                final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
                final long begin = eventCursor.getLong(1);
                final Date begin_DATE = new Date(begin);

                //final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
                final Date nowDATE = new Date(timeNow);
                final long end = eventCursor.getLong(2);
                final Date end_DATE = new Date(end);
                final long allDay = eventCursor.getLong(3);

                //function to check the time 
                 //is there a calendar event today when I run the application 
                 //if yes then print a toast message 
                 //if not then do nothing - maybe a toast do nothing!
                //Calendar Cnow = Calendar.getInstance();
                //System.out.println("Calendar now means:" + Cnow.getTimeInMillis());  //time now 
                if(timeNow >= begin && timeNow <=end){
                    //check time block for meeting 
                    System.out.println("BLOCK BLOCK BLOCK ");
                    System.out.println("The meeting is: " + title + "begin is " +  begin_DATE + "end is" + end_DATE );
                    //call blocker function 

                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("NO BLOCK NO BLOCK NO BLOCK  ");
                    //stop and restart service return to main screen with dialog box 
                }


                //System.out.println("begin:" + begin  + " End: " + end  + "all day :" + allDay + "time NOW" + timeNow );
                //assign to variables for begin and end
                Date d = new Date();
                //work with time and data               

                //System.out.println("current date" +  d.getDate() + "current hour" + d.getHours() 
                    //  + "current min" + d.getMinutes() + "current second" + d.getSeconds());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

EXCEPTION >>

```
> 12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{gb.org/gb.org.main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/instances/when
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
> content://com.android.calendar/instances/when
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at gb.org.Example.readCalendar(Example.java:62)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at gb.org.main.onCreate(main.java:12)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>     12-02 14:58:42.097: E/AndroidRuntime(12298):  ... 11 more
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="gb.org"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
- <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
- <activity android:name=".main" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
  <android.permission android:name= "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />


  </manifest>
```

Comment: Thats how ends using not documented content providers/intents...

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the problem

Comment: my fault in code >> Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, Long.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

Code in 2.2 requires a different URI for instances.

```
final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                 (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null); 

Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: You should accept your own anwser if this is the solution